# tagging and image with mark in a form using method POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a problem here.

i already can tagging a picture like working example here.

http://jsfiddle.net/K6Xnk/

but now i have an 4 image in a form. how to save this tagging in a form. after i submit them using post. i can view this 4 image with tagging i already submit.

my project is php and mysql. thanks.

```
var getAbsoluteOffset = function (el) {
var x=0, y=0;
do {
x += el.offsetLeft;
y += el.offsetTop;
} while (el = el.offsetParent);
return {x:x,y:y};
};

var createMark = function (x, y) {
return $('<img>')
.css({
position : 'absolute',
left     : x,
top      : y
})
.attr('src', 'http://img34.imageshack.us/img34/3337/imglp.png');  
};

$('img').click(function (e) {
var offset, x, y, mark;
e.preventDefault();
offset = getAbsoluteOffset(this);
x = e.pageX - offset.x;
y = e.pageY - offset.y;
mark   = createMark(x, y);
mark.appendTo(this.parentNode);
console.log('*');
});
```